# Starting Xmodmap on login (12.10)

Tags: 12.10, keyboard, startup, keyboard-layout

I'm a little confused about the automatic startup of Xmodmap. Web said I just have to create

- an .Xmodmap file in my home folder or
- an .xinitrc or .xsession script in home or
- a startup application/command launching xmodmap

but none of these worked oob.

After some messing around I found that adding a `sleep` instruction to my xmodmap script started via startup applications achieved the desired effect.

As I didn't encounter any mention of `sleep` during research: is this really needed/intended?
Should any of the other ways (plain .Xmodmap file or .xinitrc/.xsession script) work in QQ?
Plus, as recently discovered, the Xmodmap is reset after waking up from standby, any hint on what to do about that?

Thanks a lot for any help or clarification.

```
.Xmodmap (working as intended when called manually):

keycode  29 = z Z y Y leftarrow yen k K exclam Greek_kappa exclamdown NoSymbol multiply
keycode  52 = y Y z Z guillemotright U203A udiaeresis Udiaeresis numbersign NoSymbol Escape Escape union
```

Comment: What is in your `.xmodmap` file?

Comment: Hi @Seth, thanks for looking into this issue. See edited question for details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer, but perhaps I can help us to solve this mystery. I'm running Xfce on top of Debian (sorry Ubuntu fans) and am having similar trouble. I have a .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart to invoke xmodmap and this works, but the effect only lasts about 23 seconds (timed it) after which point the custom key mappings are lost. I've suspected this is a problem with Xfce overriding the key mappings and am curious if you're using xubuntu. Even if I enter the xmodmap command in a terminal just after login, it will be forgotten after about 20 seconds. However, if I wait a little while and then enter the command it is permanent (mostly, see notes about suspend below). Adding a sleep to my autostart invocation has the same effect. My ~/.config/autostart/xmodmap.desktop file currently looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=0.9.4
Type=Application
Name=xmodmap
Comment=custom key mappings
Exec=bash -c "sleep 30;xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap"
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=true
Hidden=false
```

I've set the terminal to show so I can see what's happening. This is a terrible work-around since I have to wait 30 seconds before my key map will take effect and when it does, the pc basically freezes for about 6 seconds while xmodmap processes the input file. This is acceptable (I suppose) at startup but not when I'm already in the middle of things.

I can also confirm the suspend behavior. Using the above .desktop file I get my key mappings, but upon waking up from suspend they're forgotten. Bummer, but I don't use suspend often anyway so this is a limitation I could accept.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your input! "Ubuntu fans": not too much longer :) My `sleep`in lasts 10 seconds - set it initially and never messed with it coz it "works". Am running plain Ubuntu/Unity but will change to Xfce or KDE soon b/c of some more and more severe annoyances w/ Unity. Currently I'm back on XP to get work done instead of tinkering - thought these days were over long ago and once and for all ...

Answer (score 0):

I'd got the same problem with ubuntu 12.10.

I just find one solution for me, witch is to use complete .Xmodmap filename :

```
xmodmap /home/USER/.Xmodmap
and not :
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

I put the command in the startup applications. Maybe this works also in .xinitrc. I do not test.

Comment: Hi @marcimat, thanks for your reply. I already tried the absolute path as well but to no avail.